# CakePHP 3 Paginate a result

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination, cakephp-3.0

What I'm trying to achieve is pretty simple, but I can't manage to figure out the correct way of doing it.

I have a Products table on my database. Each product has many Images and Colors, and belongs to one or many Categories.

I'm trying to create an action which receives the id of a Category and returns the Products it contains, paginated.

This is what my code looks like right now, with the two different approaches I've tried:

```
    $paginatorQuery = $this->Categories->Products->find('all', [
        'contain' => [
            'Categories' => [
                'conditions' => [
                    'category_id' => $categoryId
                ]
            ],
            'Colors',
            'Images'
        ],
        'conditions' => $conditionArray,
        'order' => [
            $session->read('productSort.field') => $session->read('productSort.direction')
        ],
    ]);

    $catProd = $this->Categories->get($categoryId, [
        'contain' => [
            'Products' => [
                'Colors',
                'Images',
                'conditions' => $conditionArray,
                'sort' => [
                    $session->read('productSort.field') => $session->read('productSort.direction')
                ],
            ]
        ],
    ]);

    // $catProd = $catProd->products;

    $products = $this->paginate($paginatorQuery);
```

The variable `$paginatorQuery` doesn't filter correctly (I knew that it wouldn't because of how flawed that logic is, but decided to try it just in case), instead it returns what would be expected (all existing products, an in the case where the product belongs to the Category with the corresponding ID, the product contains it).

The commented line `$catProd = $catProd->products` assigns to the variable `$catProd` the desired result set, but I can't manage to paginate that. I'm thinking of implementing a manual pagination by assigning limits and start to that query, but I think there must be something I'm missing which would save me the trouble.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `$paginatorQuery` should use `matching` on the categories, not `contain`. Something like this (untested):

```
$paginatorQuery = $this->Categories->Products->find('all', [
    'contain' => [
        'Colors',
        'Images'
    ],
    'conditions' => $conditionArray,
    'order' => [
        $session->read('productSort.field') => $session->read('productSort.direction')
    ],
])
->matching('Categories', function (Query $q) use ($categoryId) {
    return $q->where(['Categories.id' => $categoryId]);
});
```

See [filtering by associated data](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#filtering-by-associated-data) for more details.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. If I remember correctly, I had tried using matching before but missed the use statement, so `$categoryId` wasn't defined.